# How to use preg_replace() in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to replace a 2 characters in a string.I dont know how to use `preg_replace()`.

```
http://123-test.ab.name.com (or) http://13_test.ab.name.com (or) http://13.test.ab.name.com
```

In the above url i want to replace only ab with bc. How can i use `preg_replace()` for this situation?

Comment: For that simple a replacement, why not just use str_replace()?

Comment: please follow this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_replace.htm

Comment: I have to replace by matching 'name.com' and not all times the text will be same before .ab.

Comment: @Mark Baker: ab will not be same and we dont know its ab or anything. we can know only name.com

Comment: So you want to replace the bit in between the `.` and `.name.com`?

Comment: Why is javascript tagged - could this also be done in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like:

```
$url = "http://123-test.ab.name.com";
$url = preg_replace("/\.(.{2})(\.name\.com)/",".so$2", $url);
// Replace 'so' with whatever you want it to be.
echo $url;
```

Comment: Its works like charming!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`$link : http://123-test.ab.name.com`

`$res = explode('.',$link);`

`$to_replace = $res[count($res) - 2] ;`

`str_replace($to_repalce,"bc",$link);`

Comment: ab will not be same and we dont know its ab or anything. we can know only name.com

Answer (score 0):

For an easy replacement parameter you could use a positive lookahead like so:

```
//$uri set somewhere up here to (for example) 'http://123.test.ab.name.com'
$subdom = 'foobar';
$newURI = preg_replace('#[^\.]+(?=\.name\.com)#',$subdom,$uri);
var_dump('New URI: '.$newURI); //"New URI: http://123.test.foobar.name.com"
```